# Hardness of 3SAT-k

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, satisfiability, 3-sat

According to [these scribe notes](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.890/fall14/scribe/lec4.pdf) (and a paper), 3SAT-5 is NP-hard. The problem is defined to be: given a 3SAT formula, each variable occurs in at most 5 clauses. It is also proven that 3SAT-4 is NP-hard.

What is the computational complexity of 3SAT-$k$ for $k \le 3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper ["A Simplified NP-Complete Satisfibility Problem"](http://cedric.cnam.fr/~bentzc/INITREC/Files/CB11.pdf) given as a reference in the scribe note has actually answered your questions.

> Theorem 2.4: Every instance of $r,r$-SAT is satisfiable.

This implies that 3SAT-$3$ is satisfiable.

In addition, Section 3 gives polynomial algorithm for the 2-occurrence case for any $m$-SAT instances ($m \ge 2$).

This implies that 3SAT-$\le 2$ is polynomially tractable.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see the $r,r$-SAT in the paper.